# android socket write interrupting read

Tags: java, android, sockets

Using android 2.3.3, I have a background Service which has a socket connection.  There's a Thread that's reading from the socket continuously:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSock.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    ... do stuff
}
// Socket has been closed (?)
in.close();
```

And then in my main thread I call:

```
private void writeSocket(String line) {
    mSock.getOutputStream().write(line.getData("US-ASCII"));
}
```

When I call writeSocket, the write() does not throw an exception but I don't see the data at the other end, and the in.readLine() in the reading thread immediately returns null when the write() occurs.  From what I read, it should be safe to read and write simultaneously with the same socket from different threads?  It seems like the write is causing the socket to close, but I don't get an exception..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the other end of the connection was closed normally. This causes both the `read` and `write` to terminate. (Normally, so no exception. It's just like trying to read past the end of a file.) You can read and write simultaneously from different threads and if the socket closes, whether normally or exceptionally, both operations will fail.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be my problem.  I'm writing bad data to the socket which is causing the other end to disconnect.